# Styling small image gallery with close icon for Ionic App

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to create a small image gallery.

What I want: [Want-To-Achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JCZM.png)

What I got up till now: [Image-Up-Till-Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2EqZ.jpg)

As you can see

I got three images with different sizes, on the upper right corner I'd like to have an X (icon).

For some reason the last icon on image 3 isnt at the same position like the other two.

Thats my code:

JS:

```
   $scope.allImages = [

    "./img/ionic.png",
    "./img/background-test-black.png",
     "./img/background-test-black - Kopie.png"

  ];
```

HTML:

```
  <div>
        <ul>
        <li>
          <a ng-repeat="image in allImages">
          <img  ng-src="{{image}}" class="gallery "/>
            <i ng-click="deletePhoto(image)" class="icon ion-close delete"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.gallery {
  width: 25%;
  height: 70%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.delete {

  position: absolute;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: red;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should work with *relative* not with *absolute*.